# OnItemClickListener does not working properly when adapter contains a button with onClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener, baseadapter

I have implemented an adapter for my `ListView` which extends BaseAdapter.
My list items contain buttons that each of them have OnClickListener.

after adding OnclickLister for each item, the list's OnItemClickListener stoped working.

How can it be fixed?

the code

In my Activity -

```
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
    lv.setItemsCanFocus(true); 
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String debString = "position = " + position + " id = " + id;                
            Log.d(TAG, debString);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), debString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Contact selectedContact = dataVector.elementAt(position);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(Constants.POSITION, position);
            bundle.putString(Constants.NAME, selectedContact.getName());
            bundle.putString(Constants.MDN, selectedContact.getMdn());
            bundle.putString(Constants.STATUS, selectedContact.getStatus());
            String filePath = null;
            if(contactsImagesProperties != null || !Utils.isNullOrEmpty((String) contactsImagesProperties.get(selectedContact.getMdn()))) {
                filePath = (String) contactsImagesProperties.get(selectedContact.getMdn());
            }
            bundle.putString(Constants.IMAGE, filePath);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChildDisplayActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
        }
```

in myBaseAdapter in getView()

```
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, Constants.CHILD_ICON_WIDTH, Constants.CHILD_ICON_HEIGHT, false);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    statusView.setText(Constants.StatusCodeHandler.getStatusDesc(dataVector.elementAt(position).getStatus(), context));
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(viewIds[3]);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(Constants.ACTION, Constants.CONTACT_LOCATION_CODE);
            bundle.putString(Constants.MDN, dataVector.elementAt(position).getMdn());
            MainActivity.bundle = bundle;
            TabActivity mainActivity = (TabActivity) ((UsersListActivity)context).getParent().getParent();
            TabHost tabHost = mainActivity.getTabHost();
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(Constants.MAP_TAB_INDEX);
        }
    });
```

in myListRaw.xml -

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:id="@+id/childListImageView" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/childListTextView" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="TextView" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/childListImageView" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Child Status" 
    android:id="@+id/childListStatus" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/childListTextView" 
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/childListButton" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Loc"  
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"      
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

Comment: Some code will be better for understanding ........

Comment: You're allowing focus in your code with `lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);` - try commenting out that line or setting it to false instead.

Comment: I have changed it accoring to your comment but still have the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set your parts of row as focusable (android:focusable="true") than OnItemClickListener for ListView doen not respond. Check it out

Comment: so give us some code. it`s hard to get the problem when we can`t see what you have done

Comment: eyal, unless you have explicitly called `setFocusable ( false )`, then yes, they are focusable. You need to disable focus for the buttons, but then you'll have to manage processing clicks for the buttons. I've had this in my own apps - as soon as you process the click, you implicitly make the control focusable.

Comment: @RivieraKid - if I`m correct you can also set android:focusable = "false" in the xml file of row layout

Comment: You might be right Fixus, I'm not sure if creating a click listener also makes the control focusable by default. Either way, I think you've got the right answer.

Comment: I'm using RelativeLayout with android:focusable = "false" and still have this problem.

Comment: if you have your own Adapter i think you need to have a other xml just for displaying row. At least I think you must. And if you have it you need to set nonfocusable conf on the parts of the row. Not on the container

Comment: @eyal - can you update the code pls ? I had similar problem few days ago so maybe I`1l catch the mistake but pls update the code. show what you have atmo

Comment: If I`m correct button is a focusable items. Cause it must be focusable if you want to click it. So OnItemClickListener won`t work. for example delete the button ale leave only text elements and than check if the listener will work

Comment: Actualy it worked correctly before i added the button to the row. I think using an image which has the ability to detect onClick events.

Comment: that is what I just said :) button is a focusable item thats why OnItemClickListener won`t work. I`m 95% sure of that :) If you have a focusable item in a row you can`t click whole row (like in a Twitter application). If you don`t have ANY focusable item in row than you can set OnItemClickListener witch is invoked when you click a row, not item inside of it

Comment: Dearest friends, I'm happy to share with you that changing the ImageButton to ImageView, that has a OnclickListener, solve this problem. Thank you for your helpfull attention.