# OnItemClickListener consumes onClickListener events

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick, listener

I have read about problems that onClickListener will consume onItemClickListener Events like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090666/onitemclicklistener-and-onclicklistener-in-listview) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593181/onitemclicklistener-does-not-working-properly-when-adapter-contains-a-button-with). My Problem is exactly the other way:

I have a CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter where I place model Objects to generate a row. In My Activity i registered an onItemClickListener like so

```
//items can focus false to try to get the onItemClick-event
mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
mListView.setAdapter(this.favoritePointAdapter);
```

then in my Adapter.getView() Method I inflate my layout get my ImageView and register an OnClickListener on it like this

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    //....inflate other Views.....
    LinearLayout clickArea = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_row_favorite_point_click_area);
    clickArea.setOnClickListener(this);

   //... other logic follows ...
}
```

at least i Try to fetch this Events in my Adapter like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("ListAdapter", "onClick triggered");
            //never triggered
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.list_row_favorite_point_click_area:
        Log.d("ListAdapter", "onClick id->list_row_favorite_point_click_area");
        //never triggered
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

If you find xml of RowView interesting, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/list_row_relative_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal" 
  android:focusable="false">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_row_icon"
    android:layout_width="30dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="3dip"
    />
 <LinearLayout
   android:layout_weight="50"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">   
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/list_row_name"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#333333"
     android:text="defaultText"
     android:textStyle="bold" />         
   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/list_row_region"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="#999999"
     android:textStyle="italic"
     android:text="Region" />
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/list_row_favorite_point_click_area"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="50dip">

   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/list_row_favorite_icon"
     android:layout_width="20dip"
     android:layout_height="20dip"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_weight="0.1">
   </ImageView>
   </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

As I said, The ListView's `onItemClick` of My Activity gets triggered while I never reach onClick inside my Adapter. I think that onItemClick 'feels' responsible for the whole row and consumes TouchEvents. What can I do to work around it?

Note: I tried setItemsCanFocus(false) and focusable in my root to false, too, as mentioned in the other questions.

Comment: do you want to use both `onItemClick` and `onClick`? I used one listener at a time successfully, but not tried both of them together.

Comment: exactly, I wanna use the at them at the same time. onItemClick triggers a 'big' event -> GOTO another Activity while onClick just triggers a View to change drawable and increase priority of underlying event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using an onClickListener, I'd suggest using the onTouchListener.

Check out this tutorial, which I have used before to get the "swipe screens" in an application:
http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/29/android-switching-screens-by-dragging-over-the-touch-screen/

Also, see the android dev docs on the onTouchListener:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

Comment: It was too complicated for my purpose. I ended up registering two onClickListeners for the LinearLayouts, which don't overlap. Then I trigger another Listener on it with all Informations I need.